# Pandas - Dataframe has column with lists. How can I groupby the elements within the list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where some cells contain lists of multiple values, like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'category': [[x,y,z],[x],[y,z],[x,z]]
     'value': [20,30,20,10]
    }
)

df

Out[10]: 
     category  value
0    [x, y, z] 20
1    [x]       30
2    [y, z]    20
3    [x, z]    10
```

I'd like to group the data by unique elements in the `category` column and capture both the count of each element and mean of the `value` in which the element is present.

Intended output should look like:

```
     count  mean
x    3      20
y    2      20
z    3      16.7
```

I'm relatively familiar with simple groupby functions, and am able to create a flat list of unique elements (i.e. [x,y,z]). However, I'm not sure how to use that flat list to transform the data as desired above. Help much appreciated!

Comment: could you explain why the last mean is 18.5

Comment: My mistake. Slippery fingers on the keyboard. Updated accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use (`explode` for pandas 0.25+):

```
df.explode('category').groupby('category')['value'].agg(['count','mean'])
```

---

```
          count       mean
category                  
x             3  20.000000
y             2  20.000000
z             3  16.666667
```

For pandas version below `0.25`:

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['category'].str.len()),['value']]
  .assign(category=np.concatenate(df['category']))
 .groupby('category')['value'].agg(['count','mean']))
```

---

```
          count       mean
category                  
x             3  20.000000
y             2  20.000000
z             3  16.666667
```

Comment: @aws_apprentice thanks for the headsup , edited in the answer(I'd recommend upgrading if not :) nevertheless, thanks again)

Comment: sometimes upgrading is not an option, a well-defined, self-contained problem on StackOverflow is unfortunately a far-cry from the real world

Comment: @aws_apprentice hmm. in such cases, i have updated my answer